# Continuity of $k^{th}$ order statistic?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Consider $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for a given $x \in \mathbb{R}^n,$ $f(x)$ is the  $k^{th}$ highest co-ordinate of $x.$ For example if $n = 4, k =2$ and $x = [2,4,7,5]$ then $f(x) = 5$/ The question then is whether $f(x)$ is continuous in $x$ ? How would one go about proving this ?

Note: It is well known I think that the map from a vector to its max or min component is a continuous functions. The question now concerns the map to its  $k^{th}$ highest component being continuous or not.

Comment: Continuous for which topology?

Answer (score 1):

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant\max\{|x_i-y_i|\;;\;1\leqslant i\leqslant n\}$$
**Edit:** Recall that $f(x)\geqslant z$ if and only if the set $\{i\mid x_i\geqslant z\}$ has size at least $k$ and that $f(x)\leqslant z$ if and only if the set $\{i\mid x_i\leqslant z\}$ has size at least $n-k+1$ (when all the entries are different the sizes are exactly $k$ and $n-k+1$ but "at least" is necessary to deal with possible ex aequos).

Let $z=f(x)$. Then the size of $\{i\mid x_i\geqslant z\}$ is at least $k$ and the size of $\{i\mid x_i\leqslant z\}$ is at least $n-k+1$. Let $y$ and $t$ such that $\max\{|x_i-y_i|\;;\;1\leqslant i\leqslant n\}\leqslant t$. Then $\{i\mid y_i\geqslant z-t\}$ contains $\{i\mid x_i\geqslant z\}$ hence has size at least $k$, which implies that $f(y)\geqslant z-t$. Likewise, $\{i\mid y_i\leqslant z+t\}$ contains $\{i\mid x_i\leqslant z\}$ hence has size at least $n-k+1$, which implies that $f(y)\leqslant z-t$. Thus, $|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant t$, which proves the inequality above.

Comment: Why is this the case? Can you provide a proof?

Comment: @Ankur Sure. What did you try yourself?

Comment: The function scrambles the coordinates. So I can see the that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \max{ |x_i -y_j|; 1 \leq i,j \leq n\}$. But I don't see why your claim is true.